# Insert data into texctrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

To insert data into a textctrl i do this :

`num_items = self.lc_sources.GetItemCount() 
self.lc_sources.SetStringItem(num_items, 1, data)`

But the problem is the insertion is done after the treatment of data, well and i need to do insertion in real time.
Please how can i do this

Comment: That inserts the text immediatelly. You just have to wait a redraw for the text to show up.

Comment: it did not insert data immediatelly

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this when I need to update a ListCtrl:

self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, data)
self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, moreData)

Lately, I've been using ObjectListView instead of the ListCtrl because I think it's just easier to use and more flexible too: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/